# Need to Migrate QC ALM to Rally (including all existing folder structure and test steps)

Tags: ui-automation, rally, hp-quality-center

We are trying to migrate QC ALM to Rally. But the problem is, need to move entire existing folder structure and all test cases to Rally. I have seen in Rally help is possible by setting and running config file.

https://help.rallydev.com/QC-config-test-steps-02.pxml

I am not aware of how to run this config file as I am very new to ALM. If you know any simple way, please share.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a larger project than we can help you with here.  I'd suggest reaching out to Rally support for some help with this connector.

Answer (score 0):

We are successfully able to migrate the data from QC ALM to Rally via rest API.

Implemented a java script which will call the HTTP QC rest call to extract the folder names and test steps. After that using selenium we are able to create the same folder structure in rally and imported test steps...

QC GET API Calls to extract data:-

Folder Names:-
 http:///qcbin/rest/domains//projects/Project/test-folders?query={parent-id[]}

Test steps:-
 http:///qcbin/rest/domains//projects/Project/test-sets?query={id[]}